# How do you mock an error return value in mockery for GoLang?

Tags: go, testing, mocking, mockery

I'm using https://github.com/vektra/mockery to generate my mock files.

Assume I have this test for function `GetQualifyingListOfBooks`. The signature for the (mocked) client method `GetListOfBooks` is:

`func GetListOfBooks(ctx context.Context, in *GetListOfBooksRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*GetListOfBooksResponse, error)`

**Goal**: I want to mock the situation where `GetListOfBooks` returns an error, so I've written the following:

```
package whatever

import (
    "context"
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    mock "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    mockClients "github.com/MyOrg/MyApp/internal/app/myservice/mocks"
)

func TestGetQualifyingListOfBooks (t *testing.T) {
    client := &mockClients.BookClient{}
    client.On("GetListOfBooks", mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(nil, mock.AnythingOfType("error"))
    realInstance.bookClient = client
    b, err := GetQualifyingListOfBooks(realInstance, 10) // this calls `GetListOfBooks`
    assert.Nil(t, b)
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
}
```

but it panics with this:

```
--- FAIL: TestGetQualifyingListOfBooks (0.00s)
panic: assert: arguments: Error(1) failed because object wasn't correct type: Error(1) [recovered]
    panic: assert: arguments: Error(1) failed because object wasn't correct type: Error(1)
```

How do you mock a return value of an error?

Answer (score 2):

Changing this line

```
client.On("GetListOfBooks", mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(nil, mock.AnythingOfType("error"))
```

to this

```
client.On("GetListOfBooks", mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(nil, errors.New("hello world"))
```

did it for me.

Comment: seems unidiomatic